# Using PHP to execute cmd commands

Tags: php, cmd, shell-exec

How do I properly execute commands in the command line using php? For example I'm using the command below in the command line to convert a docx file into a pdf file:

```
pdfcreator.exe /PF"D:\Documents\sample.docx
```

Now using PHP code I want to be able to execute the same command but nothing seems to be happening:

```
<?php
shell_exec('pdfcreator.exe /PF"D:\Documents\sample.docx"');
?>
```

Is this possible in PHP?If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: ### Update Do you get any errors in your logs? What happens if you wrap that `shell_exec` call in a `var_export`? ### Original Have you tried `system()` instead? Here is the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php.

Comment: I've tried system and all the other functions for executing commands on the system(exec, shell_exec, system, pcntl_exec, passthru)

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, your answer is much appreciated.

Comment: No problem man. I probably deserved the -1, but it is good form to explain why a downvote occurred.  I didn't think you were the one who downvoted anyway.  On topic: I would check out sixeightzero's answer.  Using `escapeshellcmd()` would accomplish Piotr Olaszewski's answer but without the manual escaping.  Good luck!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
system("c:\\path\\to\\pdfcreator.exe /PF\"D:\\Documents\\sample.docx"");
```

try this.

Comment: do I still need to include the path to the executable file if I already included it in the environment variables?

Comment: I'm not for sure, but safety is pass all path.

Comment: I get a syntax error so I changed it to something like this based on the code that you provided: system('C:\\Program Files\\PDFCreator\\pdfcreator.exe /PF\"D:\\Documents\\sample.docx"');
but still no luck.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget to escape your command with [escapeshellcmd()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php). This will prevent you from having to use ugly backslashes and escape characters.

There are also other alternatives which may work:

```
`command` // back ticks drop you out of PHP mode into shell
exec('command', $output); // exec will allow you to capture the return of a command as reference
shell_exec('command'); // will return the output to a variable
system(); //as seen above.
```

Also, make sure your .exe is included within your $PATH variable. If not, include the full path for the command.

Comment: Tried the code below based on your answer, but still doesn't work. Did I mess something up:
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('pdfcreator.exe /PF"D:\Documents\sample.docx"');
`$command`;
exec($command, $output); 
shell_exec($command); 
system(); 
?>

Comment: When you run the script from CLI does it output anything? Try something like: `$command = escapeshellcmd('pdfcreator.exe /PF"D:\Documents\sample.docx" > C:\outfile');`. does anything get written to C:\outfile?