# Port address still occupied

Tags: php, node.js, port

I ran a php script on the localhost with chrome to execute the following node.js file, named test2.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var notams = require("notams");

app.get("/", function(req, resp){
notams(['LMMM', 'LMML'], { format: 'DOMESTIC' }).then(results => {
    resp.end(JSON.stringify(results));
});
});

    app.listen(1000, function (){
    console.log("Listening on Port 1337");
});
```

The php script used was the following:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("node test2.js 2>&1");
?>
```

It worked well. The only thing that did not display is the console.log msg on the browser console. (Any reason why?)

My main problem was that when I changed the script to listen on another port, the previous port (1000) was still being used by the node, even after restarting the pc and closing the browser. How can I clear up the ports from the node? P.S.I'm running on Windows 10.

Comment: _"The only thing that did not display is the console.log msg on the browser console. (Any reason why?)"_ - this will never show in the browser console, because it is ran on the server

Comment: Any way how to see it then? Is there a way to see the logs ran on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the cmd in Administration mode.
2. Punch in `netstat -a -b`
3. Checkout who uses your port
4. taskkill /f /im [pid of the port 1000 got from previous command]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Now, is there a way to do the same thing with php code? I want this php to run on a live website when a particular page loads, the result from the node gets extracted and the port then vacated.

Comment: I think this topic is covered in a different post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209509/using-php-to-execute-cmd-commands. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In node.js console.log() will display log in cmd not in browser